# Zull proxy Eureka client with ssl (https) no register to Eureka Server

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jakarta-ee, netflix-eureka

My application is composed of 6 micro services,

- Gateway API service with zull proxy
- Registration service with Eureka server
- Authentication service

The other services are purely functional. In each micro service, we have a client Eureka, which allows the service to register when it starts up on the Eureka server.
At the proxy level, we have hosted an Angular application as a static resource.
Before I decided to put the proxy in https, everything was working normally.

Now, Zull Proxy can no longer register with the Eureka server. When I enter the connection url https://localhost:443/authentication/login from the frontend (Angular at the proxy level) I am
  redirected to https://localhost/authentication/login(without port 443).

```
 Here is the configuration of Eureka server

spring.application.name=service-register
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled:true
```

```
Here is that of zull (Client Eureka)

server.port=443
spring.application.name=proxy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/DBSVERVICEPROXY?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=keystore
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.secure-port=${server.port}
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}/eureka/
```

```
Here is the configuration class for redirecting http requests to https


 @Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

I specify that the other service registers well at Eureka level.

```
This is the log message

2019-12-23 08:00:03.755[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[hresholdUpdater][0;39m [36mc.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Current renewal threshold is : 8
[2m2019-12-23 08:01:03.738[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[a-EvictionTimer][0;39m [36mc.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
[2m2019-12-23 08:02:03.738[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[a-EvictionTimer][0;39m [36mc.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
[2m2019-12-23 08:03:03.739[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[a-EvictionTimer][0;39m [36mc.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
[2m2019-12-23 08:04:03.739[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m3392[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[a-EvictionTimer][0;39m [36mc.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Running the evict task with compensationTime 0m
```

please help me, i'm really stuck

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the correct proxy configuration. Everything is working.

Here is  application.yml

```
ribbon:
  restclient:
    enabled: true
  ReadTimeout: 5000000
  eureka:
    enabled: true


zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 5000000
    socket-timeout-millis: 5000000
    max-total-connections: 1000


server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:mytruststore.jks
    key-store-password: passwordstore

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 160000000

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}

spring:
  application:
    name: proxy
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect 
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/DB_SV?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```